# How to store a boolean value using SharedPreferences in Android?

Tags: android, if-statement, boolean, sharedpreferences

I want to save boolean values and then compare them in an if-else block.

My current logic is:

```
boolean locked = true;
if (locked == true) {
    /* SETBoolean TO FALSE */
} else {
    Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(parent.getContext(), Tag1.class);
    startActivity(newActivity4);
}
```

How do I save the boolean variable which has been set to false?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); // getActivity() for Fragment
Boolean statusLocked = prefs.edit().putBoolean("locked", true).commit();
```

if you dont care about the return value (status) then you should use .apply() which is faster because its asynchronous.

```
prefs.edit().putBoolean("locked", true).apply();
```

to get them back use

```
Boolean yourLocked = prefs.getBoolean("locked", false);
```

while false is the default value when it fails or is not set

In your code it would look like this:

```
boolean locked = true;
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
if (locked) { 
//maybe you want to check it by getting the sharedpreferences. Use this instead if (locked)
// if (prefs.getBoolean("locked", locked) {
   prefs.edit().putBoolean("locked", true).commit();
} else {
   startActivity(new Intent(parent.getContext(), Tag1.class));
}
```

Comment: where I have to put this? To the if-statement?

Comment: @Emanuel: Beware: you have to **commit** your writes to the SharedPreferences. Also make sure you open an **editor** on it!

Comment: Check my source ;-) 

check carefully at true)->commit()<-

Ive fixed the typo at prefs.edit(), thx for the hint

Comment: In API level 9 or higher, you should usually prefer apply() over commit(), see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Comment: There is a [bool](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Bool) `xml` type if you need to store in `xml`

Comment: `prefs.getBoolean()` always returns `boolean` primitive -> no need in autoboxing here -> just use `boolean` instead of `Boolean`.

Comment: I had to add getApplicationContext in 
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());