# Boolean Shared Preference

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

My app is working. and now my problem is that how can I transfer it on a **sharedpreference**? I have a `achievement class`. the first achievement is "Play 1st Game" so what I do is. I set a boolean whenever the player clicks on the `play button` then I called it on my Achievement Class, if its true then I make my imageview.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE). how can I use sharedpreference on this? Im confused. and please apologized

Comment: Google not working for you ? I found a duplicate retyping the title of your question in Google ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store a boolean value using SharedPreferences in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919338/how-to-store-a-boolean-value-using-sharedpreferences-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Get a PreferenceManager to retrieve DefaultSharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Golden rule: you use a SharedPreference.Editor object to be able to write into the SharedPreference.
Let's retrieve it

```
SharedPreference.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

Put into the SharedPreferences a new Boolean

```
editor.putBoolean("ACHIEVEMENT_NAME", true);
```

and once you are done commit the changes.

```
editor.commit();
```

Last step is very important, else you lose the changes.

Little extra:

If you don't want another object by your hands, and prefer another similar approach:

```
prefs.edit().putBoolean("ACHIEVMENT_NAME", true).commit();
prefs.edit().putBoolean("ACHIEVMENT_NAME_2", true).commit();
```

This way you are forced to commit at every insert of a value, because there is not object that handles the inserts.

```
prefs.edit().putBoolean("ACHIEVMENT_NAME", true);
prefs.edit().putBoolean("ACHIEVMENT_NAME_2", true).commit();
```

This last example, would insert only ACHIEVMENT_NAME_2. Beware!

To retrieve the boolean value

```
boolean myBoolean = prefs.getBoolean(name, defaultValue);
```

now this: name is the String you used when inserting the value(so in the examples above, it's either ACHIEVMENT_NAME or ACHIEVMENT_NAME_2 ).

In case no value with given name is found, the method getBoolean would return the defaultValue you specified

Example:

```
boolean myBoolean = prefs.getBoolean("ACHIEVMENT_NAME", false);
//ACHIEVMENT_NAME exists, myBoolean gets ACHIEVMENT_NAME's value

boolean myNotFoundBoolean = prefs.getBoolean("ACHIEVMENT_NAME_3", false);
//ACHIEVMENT_NAME_3 does NOT exists, myNotFoundBoolean is false

boolean lastBooleanExample = prefs.getBoolean("ACHIEVMENT_NAME_4", true);
//ACHIEVMENT_NAME_4 does NOT exists, lastBooleanExample is true
```

In some other cases you might just need to check if certain value was being set, rather than checking what kind of value is stored.

For example, might you need to just check if a value called "GAME_COMPLETED" which might even be a value saying how many times the game was completed, but once it has been completed at least 1 time, you may unlock a new game mode.

In this case, you just need to check if prefs has GAME_COMPLETED value

```
if (prefs.contains("GAME_COMPLETED")) {
 ...
}
```

much fantasy here, hope to have given you an idea.

To clear ALL the preferences

```
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

while to remove one certain

```
editor.remove("GAME_COMPLETED");
editor.commit();
```

More(are there any more? Seems I explained pretty much everything xD) here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: sir do I need to make a xml file?

Comment: No, the XML file is automatically created (and managed)  by these API calls

Comment: how to retrieve the value of the boolean?

Comment: Did it help you in any way? Could you consider accepting my answer?