# How to display Registration screen only one time?

Tags: android

I am creating a project where I have a Registration screen, which is used for user to Register into the
Application. This Register screen should only be visible the first time, so the user can fill it and log in, but when user opens the application at the second time the application must show show Registration screen (only for registered user).

I don't understand how to do this.

I'm saving user credential in the code

```
private void setLoginData(String mobile, String pin, String emailId)
{
    SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("LoginInfo", 0);
    Editor editor;
    editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("mobileNumebr", mobile);
    editor.putString("pin", pin);
    editor.putString("emailId", emailId);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: Save a boolean to sharedpreference. When the app opens up, in your splash screen, check the boolean value to see if the user has registered. If so, go to your main screen, else open the Registration screen. Once the registration is complete, save the boolean as true.

Comment: kindly send me some code example

Comment: here i am setting user credential

Comment: private void setLoginData(String mobile, String pin, String emailId) {
  SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("LoginInfo", 0);
  Editor editor;
  editor = pref.edit();

  editor.putString("mobileNumebr", mobile);
  editor.putString("pin", pin);
  editor.putString("emailId", emailId);

  editor.apply();
 }

Comment: I have added your code to your question.

Comment: thanks for this but give me code how can i save boolean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919338/how-to-store-a-boolean-value-using-sharedpreferences-in-android

Comment: These are pretty basic questions, you should be able to find their solution on Stackoverflow pretty easily via google.

Comment: give me some reference boss

Comment: put your own efforts..!!!

Comment: We can only point you in the right direction and tell you **what** you need to do and not spoon feed you with everything.

Answer (score 0):

> Your Code :

```
private void setLoginData(String mobile, String pin, String emailId)
{
    SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("LoginInfo", 0);
    Editor editor;
    editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("mobileNumebr", mobile);
    editor.putString("pin", pin);
    editor.putString("emailId", emailId);
    editor.putBoolean("login",true);
    editor.apply();
}
```

> Above I have added one boolean shared preference parameter. Then we'll
>   use that in Splash Screen for checking that user has already
>   registered or login or not.

on Splash Screen check this condition,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("LoginInfo", 0);
// then you use
boolean isLogin = prefs.getBoolean("login", false);

if(isLogin){

  // Go to the Main Activity

}else{

 // Go to the Registration Activity

}
```

Hope it will help you my friend!

Comment: let suppose user open app first time registration screen visible to him and he dont'want to register on that time he wants to register on second time but when second time app open he directly go to main activity without registering himself

Comment: here what happening with me

Comment: if(isLogin)
         {
            //Go directly to main activity.Fragment loginScreen = new LoginScreen();
    Fragment dealMain = new DealsMainScreen();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, dealMain, null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Second run",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }

Comment: else
   { //Go directly to main activity.Fragment loginScreen = new LoginScreen();
    Fragment register = new Registration();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, register, null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this,"First Run",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }

Comment: You need to set boolean "Login" preference to TRUE only after registration or login succesful. So that If user Already registered or logged in, at that time only it will bypass Registration screen, otherwise registration screen will open.

Comment: like this: SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("LoginInfo", 0);
   //Get "hasLoggedIn" value. If the value doesn't exist yet false is returned
             boolean isLogin = settings.getBoolean("login", false);

Comment: SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("LoginInfo", 0);
   //Get "hasLoggedIn" value. If the value doesn't exist yet false is returned
             boolean isLogin = settings.getBoolean("login", false);

Comment: if(isLogin)
         {
            //Go directly to main activity.Fragment loginScreen = new LoginScreen();
    Fragment dealMain = new DealsMainScreen();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, dealMain, null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Second run",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }

Comment: I think you are setting this to TRUE first time if user registered or not. You only need to make it true Only after successful registration. Not every time. Please double check on that.

Comment: else
   { //Go directly to main activity.Fragment loginScreen = new LoginScreen();
    Fragment register = new Registration();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, register, null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this,"First Run",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }

Comment: I don't know your App Code, I have just explained the thing that you have asked. Exactly you can achieve your thing by this. Please try to implement in your flow. All the best.

Comment: i dont want code kindly send me proper implementation of true or false

Comment: Splash (Here you need to check "Login" Preference value true or not) ---> Login/Registration Screen (Here after Successful registration, You need to set Login Data, including "Login" to TRUE), If User skip Registration, then no need to set "Login" to TRUE ---> Go to the Main Activity. That is the flow. Please try to implement in your way.

Comment: like this... //setting data to sharedPreference
       setLoginData(mResponseMobileNumebr, mResponsePin, mResponseEmailId);

Comment: private void setLoginData(String mobile, String pin, String emailId) {
  SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  Editor editor;
  editor = pref.edit();

  editor.putString("mobileNumebr", mobile);
  editor.putString("pin", pin);
  editor.putString("emailId", emailId);
  editor.putBoolean("login",true);
  editor.apply();
 }

Comment: Yes, exactly after Successful registration you need to do this thing.

Comment: but I am not setting login in true:-    setLoginData(mResponseMobileNumebr, mResponsePin, mResponseEmailId)

Comment: Please my friend check again your code. It's very basic condition check for bypass user if he is logged in. Please go through the whole code flow. I tried my best to explain you. If you feel it helped you somewhere, Kindly upvote my friend.

Comment: kindly tell me i m doing right :-setLoginData(String mobile, String pin, String emailId, Boolean true) {
  SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  Editor editor;
  editor = pref.edit();

  editor.putString("mobileNumebr", mobile);
  editor.putString("pin", pin);
  editor.putString("emailId", emailId);
  editor.putBoolean("login",true);
  editor.apply();
 }

Comment: //setting data to sharedPreference
       setLoginData(mResponseMobileNumebr, mResponsePin, mResponseEmailId);

Comment: Yes, function what you are using that code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html The Account manager is a bit tricky It will collect credentials for accounts associated with your app only once and handle authentication transparently from then on if no exceptions occur. If lets say the wife changed credentials on her device and forgot to inform you, well Account manager will prompt you for the new password. The user can even go to the phone settings/accounts and access things that way once you implement Account Manager. The above is strictly for the local device but chances are you want to actually use credentials stored on a local device to authenticate with a remote server. if this is the case check this out https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html?q=authenticationactivity#q=authenticationactivity