# How to save boolean value in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, boolean

How can I save a boolean value even if I close the app and open it again? I'm new to android and I only know that things like that can be saved by using user defaults but I don't what to do in Android Studio.

Here is the boolean I want to save:

```
  var pressed: Boolean? = false

   pressed = true //I want this state to be saved
```

Comment: This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919338/how-to-store-a-boolean-value-using-sharedpreferences-in-android) showing how to use SharedPreferences might help.

Comment: @Michael Krause, I tried to use the answer but it didn't work.

Comment: How it did not work?